# ¿Cuándo se ponen los paréntesis en Laravel y cuando no?

Tags: php, laravel, relaciones, colecciones

Hay una cosa muy curiosa que me pasa con Laravel, y es que no termino de entender por qué a veces hay que poner paréntesis y otras veces no. Ejemplo:

Tengo un Accesor que me dice el carro activo de un usuario (carro de la compra).

Cuando lo pongo así NO funciona:

```
$carrito = $this->carts->where('estado', 'activo')->first();
```

El fallo (Trying to get property 'carrito_activo' of non-object), es decir, cuando instancia una variable del modelo App\User para saber cual es su carro activo.

Sin embargo, cuando le pongo paréntesis a la relación que es carts dentro de productos (public function carts()).

Sí que me funciona.

```
$carrito = $this->carts()->where('estado', 'activo')->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En las relaciones de Laravel, cuando las llamas **CON** paréntesis, estás llamando el método definido en el modelo, que es la relación como tal, no son objetos.

```
/**
 * Get the Carts associated with the user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function carts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Cuando llamas a la relación **SIN** paréntesis, estás llamando el/los objetos que están relacionados con el objeto referente, es como si hicieras la consulta al modelo.

```
dump($user->carts); // arroja una colección de objetos (normalmente)
```

---

Una forma sencilla de ver la diferencia, es obteniendo el mismo resultado con las dos formas mencionadas:

```
$user->carts;
```

es lo mismo que

```
$user->carts()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Las relaciones de los modelos en laravel pretenden que puedan utilizarse directamente desde el modelo inicial de forma que

1. Si tu modelo usuario tiene la función carts y esta es

```
return $this->hasMany(Cars::class);
```

Entonces lo que hace la función $this->carts es

```
Carts::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

Observa que inicia el query builder pero termina con `get` motivo por el cual te arroja el error que mencionas

2. En cambio si en lugar de hasMany tienes

```
return $this->hasOne(Cars::class);
```

Entonces lo que hace la función $this->carts es

```
Carts::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
```

Hace lo mismo pero la última función en `first`, ahí si funcionaria de la forma que esperas

3. Para ambos casos, si necesitas ser más especifico a la hora de buscar los elementos de las relaciones, debes "abrir" el query builder y para ello es el uso de los paréntesis, entonces al ejecutar

```
$this->cards()
```

Inicias lo siguiente

```
Cards::where('user_id', $user->id);
```

Ahi puedes agregar cualquier función de eloquent, pero debes finalizar con `get` o `first`